# Updating multiple columns in a single SQL query

Tags: sql

Table `Student` has two columns, `Roll_no` & `Attendance`. In the `Attendance` column, 0 denotes absent, while 1 denotes present.

One day teacher marked absent students as present and present as absent. So how can we correct the table using a single SQL update query?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: it's an interview question. So any DB query will do I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating single column only.

```sql
UPDATE Student
SET Attendance = CASE Attendance WHEN 1 THEN 0 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
WHERE Day = <Day When It was wrongly updated>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking the same but there was no date column mentioned in the question. So is there any way to modify the query to update data without using any date?

Comment: If we dont use where clause, all dates will get affected. it can cause data corruption.

Comment: okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: .Hope this might work for the above query]
this is 1 preferred solution in Oracle RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

this is  another approach Oracle RDBMS but is quiet lengthy
update student
set attendence=1 where attendence=0
set attendence=0 where attendence=1;